# как исправить баг flex на IE11?

Tags: css3, flexbox

вот код:

```
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

https://codepen.io/Flector/pen/vxMVRe
```

работает отлично везде, кроме IE.
как исправить этот код, чтобы IE выводил навигацию в несколько строчек?

[image: навигация в ie11]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Необходимо добавить - `flex-wrap: wrap;` для `.flex-container`

Comment: огромное спасибо!